# remove document objectid only in populated array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm having a really difficult time trying to remove the objectids from an array using a populated query.

this is my Schema

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  books: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book'}]
  }
);

var bookSchema = new Schema({
  bookid: {type:String, unique:true, required:true},
  imgURL: String,
  fortrade: Boolean
});
```

The problem is with the query shown below.  it removes removes the book schema item when I only want it to remove the objectid in the books array.

```
users.findOne({'_id':userid}).populate('books').exec(function(usererr,userdata){
        if (usererr) return console.error(usererr);

        userdata.books.forEach(function(elm,idx){
            if(elm.bookid==_book.bookid){
                userdata.books[idx].remove();
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem, It would be really helpful if you give the solution in detail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If all you want to do is select the refernced fields in the output of the related object from `.populate()`, then simply supply the list of either the fields you want, or want to remove within the [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) call:

```js
users.findOne({'_id':userid})
    .populate('books',"-_id")
    .exec(function(usererr,userdata){
       // userdata contains related without the _id field
    });
```

So the second parameter there in the `.populate()` specifies the fields you want to select in the subsequent query. The `-` notation means to "exclude" the field, otherwise you need to specify a list of fields to specifically include.

This is basic MongoDB field "projection". One rule here is that you cannot "mix" both include or exclude. So either be explicit:

```js
.populate('books','bookid imgURL forTrade')
```

Or just exlcude the "special" fields:

```js
.populate('books', '-_id -__v')
```

where `_id` is the general "always included" primary key, and `__v` is the mongoose generated version key, which you also might not want in results.

Also see [Limit Fields to Return in a Query](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) from the core documentation, as well as the mongoose shortened syntax for this under [`.select()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select).

Comment: You are a savior!