# Exclude certain attributes from object using the populate from mongodb using aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregate

I want to exclude for example email and address using populate() function from mongodb, just get the name from it:

Example:

```
const results = await Seller.aggregate(aggregatePipeline).exec();
const sellers = await Seller.populate(results, { path: "user" });
```

When populating the user instead of having:

```
...
user: {
    email: "hgjh@gmail.com",
    address:{},
    name: "name"
}
```

I want to only have (exclude certain data from the path):

```
...
user: {
   name: "name"
}
```

Comment: You can use **[unset](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/)** in aggregation pipeline. 

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35121258) for populate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either,

```
const sellers = await Seller.populate(results, { path: "user", select: '- 
email -address'  });
```

or

```
const sellers = await Seller.populate(results, { path: "user", select: 
'name'  });
```

Answer (score 2):

As i understand mongoose documentation  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html, populate as $lookup is use to resolve a relation with other collection.

> MongoDB has the join-like $lookup aggregation operator in versions >= 3.2. Mongoose has a more powerful alternative called populate(), **which lets you reference documents in other collections.**

In your case, you don't need to resolve a field with an other collection. You already have the final data you target . You could use $project at the end of your pipeline aggregation to keep only name field, like :

`{ $project: { name:1 } }`

Let me know if i helped you.

Edit :

I read too fast, if you have this data res after the populate and not after the aggreg, you may `select` your final field, like is said
here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72481338/16205278

```
user: {
    email: "hgjh@gmail.com",
    address:{},
    name: "name"
}
```